# ошибка пути в get_template_directory() в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

вызываю функцию get_template_directory()  и получаю путь D:\OpenServer\domains\wp.local/wp-content/themes/
как видно имеем "/" и "\", не могу найти как их настроить, для пути до корневой папки, чтоб путь правильно был прописан.

Comment: "чтоб путь правильно был прописан" - нужно использовать линукс а не винду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

цитата с [этого](https://wp-kama.ru) сайта:

**get_stylesheet_directory()**

Получает абсолютный путь до каталога, где находится текущий файл стилей родительской или дочерней темы. Не содержит закрывающего слэша (/).

[источник](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_stylesheet_directory)

```
echo get_stylesheet_directory();
// вернет: /home/k/kama/site.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/themename
```

**wp_normalize_path()**

Заменяет обратные слэши (в windows) на прямые слэши и двойные слэши на одинарные.

[источник](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_normalize_path)

```
$path = '\www\site.ru\\wp-content\/\uploads//file.jpg';
$path = wp_normalize_path( $path );
echo $path;
// выведет: /www/site.ru/wp-content/uploads/file.jpg
```

Comment: у него вопрос в другом - на openServer это работает через ж..., смешивая прямые и обратные слеши

Comment: нет, возвращает тот же путь D:\OpenServer\domains\wp.local/wp-content/themes/

Comment: и функции get_template_directory и get_stylesheet_directory - для разных вещей.

Comment: wp_normalize_path( $path ); - в целом помогает единственно что D:/OpenServer/ (а именно D:/ <= слеш) тоже поменял, но это уме мелочи, лечится       $All_Path   =   get_template_directory();

$Part_Path  =   substr($All_Path, 3);

$Part_Path  =   wp_normalize_path($Part_Path);

$All_Path   =   substr_replace($All_Path, $Part_Path, 3);

Comment: всем спасибо!!!)

Comment: помогать это приятно)